# C++: comparing current time to next work time

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I am working on an automation program. The idea is that after performing an action it increments the time that the next action should be performed. I chose this method rather than simple `Sleep()` statements because I am waiting on user keyboard input which does various things.

The issue that I am encountering is that `std::chrono::steady_clock::now() > next_work_period` always seems to evaluate to true, thus making it so there is no wait period.

This is my first time working with these functions. I appreciate any help!

```
auto next_work_period = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    while (1) {

        // To keep disk usage low, 100 may need to be changed
        Sleep(100);

        // If current time is time to do next action
        if (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() > next_work_period) {

            std::cout << "Has been 20 seconds" << endl;

            // Calculate next click time, 20 seconds from now
            next_work_period += std::chrono::milliseconds((20) * 1000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about sleeping ***until*** the next work period? Like this:

```
auto next_work_period = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

while (1) {

    std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_work_period);

    doTheThing();

    // Calculate next click time, 20 seconds from now
    next_work_period += std::chrono::seconds(20);
}
```

Comment: Will that still allow me to properly check for key presses during the sleep until, or does it pause at that line similar to a regular sleep statement?

Comment: @Grehgous This sleeps only the current thread. All other threads keep running just fine.